# IIf method does not work with IsDBNull(Guid.empty)

Tags: vb.net-2010, iif-function

For example,

```
Dim Test as Guid 

Test = IIf(IsDBNull(DataReader("ID")), Guid.Empty, DataReader("ID"))
```

They caused an error - "Unrecognized guid format"

I was trying to do if statement below

```
If(IsDBull(DataReader("ID")) Then
   Test = Guid.Emtpy
Else
   Test = DataReader("ID")
End If
```

It worked for me.

Does 4.0 framework have an issue with IIf method handling empty guid value or non-empty guid value?

Answer (score 0):

logically your codes is same and should work in both way.
yes i think its a issue in version 4.0
but you try in this way also

```
Test = IIf(IsDBNull(DataReader("ID"))=true, Guid.Empty, DataReader("ID"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIf function does not use short-circuit evaluation, it always evaluates all three of its arguments. Which means that even if `IsDBNull(DataReader("ID"))` equates to true, `DataReader("ID")` is still evaluated and the probable cause for your error.

This has at least been the case since VB.Net came around so it's not a framework issue.